# Effect of high temperatures on plant stomata

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

My biology textbook states that stomatal closure occurs at high temperatures to avoid water loss. Another stackexchange thread I can find ([What is the effect of temperature and carbon dioxide on the opening and closing of stomata?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/37418/what-is-the-effect-of-temperature-and-carbon-dioxide-on-the-opening-and-closing/46004#46004)) agrees with this, however most actual studies on the subject I can find talk about stomatal opening occurring at higher temperatures, but say the effect if the plant is experiencing water stress.

Does anyone know why there is conflicting info on this, and which source is correct?

Comment: I wondered the same. According to biology lectures I had stomata cells are opened by turgor (water pressure within cells). There are several depicted mechanisms. In some illustrations there is like a lid sitting on top of the stomata and turgor opens the lid by pushing it upwards. In other turgor deforms the cells so that they form a hole between them (a stomata). According to this theory as long as there is enough water available stomata should remain open, but probably other mechanisms exist.